# gRPC slow communication together with pyGTK

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, pygtk, grpc

I am using pyGTK and a python gRPC server. Both in a very basic setup.

I just create a `gtk.Window()`, `show()` it and run a `gtk.main()` loop.

My server starts like that:

```
def startServing():
    global server
    print("Starting server...")
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    laserClient_pb2_grpc.add_LComServicer_to_server(LCom(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50053') # [::] is the same as 0.0.0.0    server.start()
    print("Server is running...")
```

So I call:

```
try:
    startServing()
    gtk.main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

This creates the window correctly but I never receive a request from my Java client. (The java client is not the problem.)

I read a lot on the internet and I do not understand all of the pyGTK thread handling but I tried `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` right before `startServing()` and I received the requests. However I receive just 1 request per second whereas my client sends a request every 50ms. If I delete `gtk.main()` and add a while loop:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
```

**...I receive requests nearly every 50 to 100ms. This is the expected behaviour!**

However my window won't get updated since there is no `gtk.main()` loop anymore. I even tried adding:

```
while True:
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

But this gives, again, just 1 request per second.

I have no idea what I should do now. I really want to use gRPC and pyGTK together in the same program.

Comment: Is there any way to run gRPC without a ThreadPoolExecutor or is there an alternative to gtk's main loop?

Comment: How much do you know about pyGTK's threading model? Could it be doing anything that would interfere with the execution of the threads in the thread pool that you passed to `grpc.server`?